# Accessing array of objects in an object using Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I am trying to have an array of 30 recipes shown on my view with data from an API call.

```
  // app.js
  angular.module('recipeApp', [])
  .controller('RecipesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mainview = [];

  $http.get('/API')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.mainview = response.data;
    });

  // index.html
  <html lang="en" ng-app="recipeApp">
  <body ng-controller="RecipesCtrl">
  {{mainview}} //this outputs the same data shown on the API call.
               // when I try 'ng-repeat' nothing shows up at all

  // data from API call (this is just a sample of the data. there is really an array of 30 objects in "recipes")
  {
  "count": 30,
  "recipes": [
    {
      "publisher": "Closet Cooking",
      "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35382",
      "title": "Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
      "source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/04/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
      "recipe_id": "35382",
      "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg",
      "social_rank": 100,
      "publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com"
    },
    {
      "publisher": "The Pioneer Woman",
      "f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/47024",
      "title": "Perfect Iced Coffee",
      "source_url": "http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/06/perfect-iced-coffee/",
      "recipe_id": "47024",
      "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/icedcoffee5766.jpg",
      "social_rank": 100,
      "publisher_url": "http://thepioneerwoman.com"
    },
```

When I have {{mainview}} in the html, it shows the same as above, but how can I have it so all 30 recipes are looped in the view? I looked into ng-repeat, but I am very new to Angular and couldn't figure it out. Any information on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-repeat like this:

```html
<body ng-controller="RecipesCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="recipe in mainview.recipes">{{recipe}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

It will generate a **li** element for every recipe in your array. You can access the properties of a recipe using . as you would in javascript.

```
{{recipe.publisher}}
```

Note: ng-repeat works with any elements, I used ul and li for show purposes only.

Comment: There are no errors and nothing shows up when I use this.

Comment: you did not post your html code in the question, could you post that?

Comment: I made a quick plunkr with the data, and it works just fine. :) Maybe there's an issue in a part of the code you are not showing us. http://plnkr.co/edit/1m6MRTXhWfqwOGi8yOrk

Comment: The reason why it wasn't working was because the data that came back from the API was a string. I needed to parse it to JSON. After that, your answer worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="recipe in mainview.recipes">
    <a href="{{recipe.source_url}}">{{recipe.title}}</a>
    <br />
    - {{recipe.publisher}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are no errors and nothing shows up when I use this.

Comment: so, now it depends how you are using the controller in your view. If you are using alias, like `ng-controller="ctrl as viewCtrl"`, you need to make changed in repeater like `<li ng-repeat="recipe in ctrl.mainview.recipes">`,  otherwise youcan use the above code.

Comment: The reason why it wasn't working was because the data that came back from the API was a string. I needed to parse it to JSON. After that, your answer worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a view fragment like:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in mainview.recipes">
    <div>
        <label>Publisher</label><span>{{item.publisher}}</span>
    <div>
    <div>
        <label>Title</label><span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <div>
    ...
</div>
```

where ... is whatever else you want to display in the view. Documentation at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat (though I know you've read it (: )

Comment: There are no errors and nothing shows up when I use this.